# Passing an assoc array value to Ajax in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Actually I am trying to do a graph chart for all reports for that am using jQChart plugins. I have done the graph report by PHP but my head need that report with animation so I go to jQChart but I don't know how to pass the assoc array values to Ajax.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT vaccum_value,date FROM vaccum_details where serial_number='10P1005'");
$data1=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
    $data1[$row['date']]=$row['vaccum_value'];
}  

$data = Array ( "28-Sep-2012" => 31.6, "04-Oct-2012" => 0.99, "03-Oct-2012" => -3 );
```

but I need to pass this result to Ajax and then convert to like this below:

> data: [['28-Sep-2012', 31.6], ['04-Oct-2012', 0.99], ['03-Oct-2012', -3]]

Detailed Script for your reference:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#jqChart').jqChart({ title: { text: 'Animation' }, animation: { delayTime: 1, duration: 2 }, series: [ { type: 'line', title: 'Line', data: [['A', 69], ['B', 57], ['C', 86], ['D', 23], ['E', 70], ['F', 60], ['D', 88], ['H', 22]] } ] }); }); 
</script>
```

Comment: i fetch a result from mysql by using php. i have used assoc array. here below my code:

Comment: Don't post your code in comments.. You can edit your question

Comment: I got a result like below.
    
    $data = Array ( "28-Sep-2012" => 31.6, "04-Oct-2012" => 0.99, "03-Oct-2012" => -3 );
    
    but i need to pass this result to ajax and then convert to like this below:
    
    data: [['28-Sep-2012', 31.6], ['04-Oct-2012', 0.99], ['03-Oct-2012', -3]]

Comment: Detailed Script for your reference:
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
title: { text: 'Animation' },
animation: { delayTime: 1,
duration: 2
},
series: [
{
                                    type: 'line',
                                    title: 'Line',
                                    data: [['A', 69], ['B', 57], ['C', 86], ['D', 23], ['E', 70], ['F', 60], ['D', 88], ['H', 22]]
                                }
                            ]
                });
            });
        </script>

Comment: you can edit your question and add all relevant information to the question

Comment: Edit your question to add code, don't post it as comments.

Comment: hi bhuvan, how to pass the array to jquery...

Answer (score 1):

Encode the array using JSON and pass to jQuery.

```
   json_encode($array);
```

in jQuery, parse the JSON string to get the array values:

```
  jQuery.parseJSON(jsonstring);
```

Check : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Place a call from the jQuery to the PHP script using jQuery.get - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Check the edit. You can use any ajax calls. jQuery.get is just one way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT vaccum_value,date FROM vaccum_details where serial_number='10P1005'");
$data1=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
    $data1[$row['date']]=$row['vaccum_value'];
}
json_encode($data1);
```

In your jQuery+ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:'serial_number=10P1005',
        url: "your_file.php",
        success: function(jsonData){
            var jsonArray = eval('(' + jsonData + ')');

            if(jsonArray.date == 'condition'){
                // some action here
            }else{
                // some other action hera
            }



        }
    },"json");
```

Comment: hi learner thanks for your answer... i can understand your code but i don't know how to join your code with my code... shall i add jqchart code to your code which i have posted on top?

Comment: Is this correct?   `<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
title: { text: 'Animation' },
animation: {
delayTime: 1,
duration: 2
},
//jQuery.parseJSON(jsonstring);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonstring);
alert(obj);
series: [
{
type: 'line',
title: 'Line',
data: [['A', 69], ['B', 57], ['C', 86], ['D', 23], ['E', 70], ['F', 60], ['D', 88], ['H', 22]]
                            }
                        ]
            });
        });
    </script>`